# Is item-based collaborative filtering the same thing as content-based filtering?

Tags: comparison, terminology, recommender-system

According to [this Google dev page](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/recommendation/overview/candidate-generation)

> **content-based filtering**
>
> Uses similarity between items to recommend items similar to what the
> user likes.
>
> **collaborative filtering**
>
> Uses similarities between queries and items simultaneously to provide >recommendations.

With the items and query defined [here](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/recommendation/overview/terminology)

> **Items (also known as documents)**
>
> The entities a system recommends. For the Google Play store, the items
> are apps to install. For YouTube, the items are videos.
>
> **Query (also known as context)**
>
> The information a system uses to make recommendations. Queries can be
> a combination of the following:
>
> **user information**
>
> the id of the user
>
> items that users previously interacted with
>
> **additional context**
>
> time of day
>
> the user's device"

But I also see the term "Item-based Collaborative Filtering" thrown around sometimes, e.g. [here](https://hivemall.incubator.apache.org/userguide/recommend/item_based_cf.html), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Item-item_collaborative_filtering) and [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/comprehensive-guide-on-item-based-recommendation-systems-d67e40e2b75d).

Is this item based collaborative filtering the same thing as content based filtering?